# Как изменить external library в maven проекте?

Tags: intellij-idea, maven, repository, library

В моем maven проекте есть следующая зависимость, которая успешно скачивается и работает.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.thucydides</groupId>
    <artifactId>thucydides-core</artifactId>
    <version>${thucydides.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Сейчас добавляю в проект **yandex html elements**, но не могу выполнить одно действие - отредактировать класс `SmartElementProxyCreator.java` в
`thucydides/thucydides-сore/src/main/java/net/thucydides/core/annotations/locators`.

Idea всегда говорит о том что файл **read only**, что логично, так как это внешний репозитарий.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как мне правильно изменить этот класс внешней библиотеки и сделать **deploy** в свой проект?

Comment: Расскажите подробнее о необходимости изменения класса

Comment: В классе, в 2 методах необходимо закомментировать по три строки кода и добавить по одной новой

Comment: Да это понятно, что вам физически нужно произвести изменения, вопрос в том, зачем

Comment: Так настраивается интеграция с Thucydides у yandex html elements для версии 0.9.203. По крайней мере так указано в моем задании для выполнения (обучаюсь thucydides). То что для новой версии такого нет - уже видел на оф сайте. Но по заданию нужно использовать именно старую версию и задеплоить в репозитарий

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы изменить класс - качаете исходники данной библиотеки, далее меняете класс, собираете и приатачиваете к проекту.

Comment: радикально) а как же изменение байт кода в блокноте, реверс компиляция и прочие радости жизни?)

Comment: @pavel Боюсь это не тот случай)

Comment: Сделал импорт через idea - file - project structure - libraries - add - from maven, далее указал net.thucydides:thucydides-core:0.9.203, проставил checkbox Sources. В итоге в папку lib в проекте скачалось много файлов и среди них был нужный jar thucydides-core-0.9.203-sources.jar, который я поправил. Правильная ли последовательность?

Answer (score 1):

Дополню следующими конкретными шагами для таких же зеленых, как я:
1) Скачать исходники с гита для нужной версии и распаковать
2) Открыть в IDE как maven проект, главный из всех называется thucydides
3) Изменить нужный класс
4) Сделать mvn compile
5) mvn install - так jar файл этого проекта окажется в локальном репозитарии 
6) Закрыть этот проект
7) Открыть или создать новый проект
8) в pom файле указать dependency на этот jar
9) убедиться что версии junit, maven plugins, selenium указанные в pomнике совместимы. Если у вас на этапе compile-install возникают ошибки, скорее всего проблема в версиях